# Perl one liner to remove multiple line

Tags: regex, perl

input file is

```
<section_begin>  mxsqlc


*** WARNING[13052] Cursor C is not fetched.
<section_end>
<section_begin>  b2.lst
*


*** WARNING[13052] Cursor C is not fetched.

0 errors, 1 warnings in SQL C file "b2.ppp".
<section_end>
<section_begin>  b2s0
SQLCODE=0
SQLSTATE=00000
a=10, b=abc, c=20
SQLCODE=0
SQLSTATE=00000
a=10, b=abc      , c=10, d=xyz      
<section_end>
```

expecting output without below lines.

```
<section_end>
<section_begin>  b2s0
```

my code is

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\<section_end\>(\s*|.*lst)?\s*$/' b2exp
```

It removes all `<section_end>` lines and doesn't remove this line `<section_begin>  *.lst`

Comment: Because you aren't making any attempt to match it? Maybe you want `/^<section_(begin|end)>(\s*|.*lst)?\s*$/i`.

Comment: Or may be more restrictive `/^<section_(?:end>|begin>.*\.lst)\s*$/`.

Comment: I have used the same. but no luck perl -ne 'print unless /^<section_(begin|end)>(\s*|.*lst)?\s*$/i' b2exp returns <section_begin>  mxsqlc


*** WARNING[13052] Cursor C is not fetched.
*


*** WARNING[13052] Cursor C is not fetched.

0 errors, 1 warnings in SQL C file "b2.ppp".
<section_begin>  b2s0
SQLCODE=0
SQLSTATE=00000
a=10, b=abc, c=20
SQLCODE=0
SQLSTATE=00000
a=10, b=abc      , c=10, d=xyz. <section_end> is missing :(

Answer (score 2):

keep it simple

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\<section_/' b2exp
```

bit more complicated

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\<section_(end|begin)\>/' b2exp
```

Ah, your question isn't clear. ( to me, perhaps it is really)

I now read it as 
"I have some sections marked out with `<section_begin>   tagname`
at the start and `</section_end>` at the end.
  I wish to exclude the sections with a particular tagname, `bs20` in the example.  I wish to keep all other lines
"

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN {$p=1}  $p=0 if /section_begin.*b2s0/; print if $p; $p=1 if /<section_end>/;' ex.txt
```

Comment: expecting output is `<section_begin>  mxsqlc


*** WARNING[13052] Cursor C is not fetched.
*


*** WARNING[13052] Cursor C is not fetched.

0 errors, 1 warnings in SQL C file "b2.ppp".
<section_end>
<section_begin>  b2s0
SQLCODE=0
SQLSTATE=00000
a=10, b=abc, c=20
SQLCODE=0
SQLSTATE=00000
a=10, b=abc      , c=10, d=xyz      
<section_end>`

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to merge the section with `lst` with the next section (and remove the stuff on the same line after the next section's begin tag), I would go with Awk instead.

```
awk '/<section_end>/ && lst { next }
    /<section_begin>/ && lst { lst=0; next }
    /<section_begin>.*lst/ {lst=1}
    1' b2exp
```

The same thing can be done in Perl, of course; the simplest one-liner with `perl -0777 -pe 's/.../.../s' file` will be a lot less memory-efficient because of buffering.

```
perl -0777 -pe 's%(<section_begin>[^\n]*lst.*?)\n<section_end>\n<section_begin>[^\n]%$1%s' b2exp
```

This will read the whole file into memory (`-0777`) and replace the multi-line regexp.  The greedy match `.*?` will make the match as short as possible, i.e. not span past a match on the rest of the pattern (newline, end tag, newline, begin tag optionally followed by non-newline data).  We also take care to use `[^\n]` where we want to keep matches on the same line, since the `/s` flag turns `.` into a wildcard which can also match newlines.